# Running many commands via batch, running into annoying issue

Tags: windows, batch-file, rmdir

What I am trying to do is automate moving downloads, deleting unneeded files and then running a program through command line as well as who knows what else I think up of going through this quest.  Here I have the beginning of my first `.bat` file:

**`move.bat`**:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /a:-D /s /b') do move "%%f" .
for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /a:D /s /b') do rd "%%f"
del "C:\Downloads\*.jpg"
del "C:\Downloads\*.png"
del "C:\Downloads\*.gif"
del "C:\Downloads\*.txt"
del "C:\Downloads\*.nfo"
move "C:\Downloads\*.mp4" "C:\Movies\"
cd "C:\program files\filebot\"
filebot -rename c:\movies
copy "E:\Documents\Tweaks&commands\folderize.bat" "C:\Movies"
cd "C:\Movies\"
folderize.bat
ping 192.0.2.2 -n 1 -w 4000 > nul
rmdir /S /Q "C:\movies\folderize"
```

Now, everything **works just fine** up to running `folderize.bat`.

**`Folderize.bat`**:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%a in (*.eng*) do (
  set file=%%a
  ren "!file!" "!file:_=!"
)
@echo off
for %%a in (*.*) do (
md "%%~na" 2>nul
move "%%a" "%%~na"
)
```

`Folderize.bat` does exactly what it's supposed to do, but if I run that it will include itself, creating a folder named folderize and then moving itself into there.  Ok, not a problem, I'll just do a `rmdir` and all is well.

**That doesn't work**.

In `Move.bat` I originally tried without the `ping` command line. I added that line as I thought it just needed a couple seconds before attempting delete (honestly just a stab in the dark). That was a no go as well.

I opened a `cmd` prompt and ran it manually to see what would happen.  After folderize is initialized, it is then moved into it's own folder prompting that the batch file could not be found and terminates.

**Is there a way that I can edit `folderize.bat` to exclude `.bat` files from being placed in a folder or really just exclude itself**?

Comment: Thanks for the edits, I'm aware now for next post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like it's moving everything in your `folderize.bat` batch file.  Maybe you should put a filter on it like so:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%a in (*.eng*) do (
  set file=%%a
  ren "!file!" "!file:_=!"
)
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1* delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /o:-n ^| findstr /iv "folderize.bat"') do (
md "%%~na" 2>nul
move "%%a" "%%~na"
)
```

Also, you use use the `call` command in your `move.bat`, like so:

```
call folderize.bat
```